# FFMPeg hstack throwing height exception

Tags: ffmpeg

I am currently trying to horizontally stack multiple video files and receiving this error

```
[Parsed_hstack_6 @ 000001bd83f8b4c0] Input 1 height 480 does not match input 0 height 
360.12x
[Parsed_hstack_6 @ 000001bd83f8b4c0] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_hstack_6
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

This is my command.

```
ffmpeg -i RT05974d20e9550b89697b15f8bc3feb78.mkv -i RTb295d0534191e1acb22a45bb971a12e6.mka -i RTc2de0d06575c6c225b44dbce73104ed8.mkv -i RT3904b3a60273760ec9e9c181ea35bdc4.mka -i RT13386752138abbe5eb941da3f7fdfdc5.mka -i RTe31da14ad7c898ad8d8ce6bbafc5e387.mkv -i RT103bfe5f4b129860f69cd8e820f3a10b.mka -i RT2e5859b6a555070f3305735c698966d0.mka -filter_complex "[2:v]tpad=start_duration=120:color=black[vpad]; [3:a]adelay=120000:all=1[a2pad]; [4:a]adelay=150000:all=1[a3pad]; [5:v]tpad=start_duration=20:color=black[v2pad]; [6:a]adelay=200000:all=1[a5pad]; [7:a]adelay=240000:all=1[a6pad]; [0:v][vpad][v2pad]hstack=inputs=3[vout]; [1:a][a2pad][a3pad][a5pad][a6pad]amix=inputs=5:weights=1|1|1|1|1[aout]" -map [vout] -map [aout] output.mkv
```

I then also checked each file individually to make sure that their height and width were correct.

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=p=0:s=x RT05974d20e9550b89697b15f8bc3feb78.mkv
640x480
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=p=0:s=x RTc2de0d06575c6c225b44dbce73104ed8.mkv
640x480
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=p=0:s=x RTe31da14ad7c898ad8d8ce6bbafc5e387.mkv
640x480
```

Full log pasted here - https://pastebin.com/0XEipXjA
Log when only two files are used - https://pastebin.com/AVYisBeh
Log when that first video file is not used (works) - https://pastebin.com/8YfHRsQ1

What am I doing incorrectly?